# CSS-transitions font-size does not work

Tags: css, css-transitions, font-size

Just trying to imitate an effect you can find here: (https://www.gaastrastore.com/en-de/men):

(top menu, mouse over on the list items, entry moves to the right and gets two arrows in the front)

I'm trying to get those two arrows working. I got the move to the right working. The arrows I tried to get going using transition and font-size from 0px to 10px. Any ideas? I'd like to stick with CSS if possible.

Cheers

Comment: Why would the arrows use `font-size`?

Comment: Hi, I just put ">>" into a <span>, which I tried to transform separately. I guess I could just use an image. I'm just wondering why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `font-size` to increase from font-size `0px to 10px`, you can use `margin-left` to hide and show `span` tag on which you are adding that transition as below,

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul > li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul > li > span {
  margin-left: -10px;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

ul > li:hover > span {
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>></span> Home</li>
  <li><span>></span> About</li>
  <li><span>></span> Contact</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @D. Astl font-size here will give scaling effect, whereas you want it to flow-in on hover and hide on hover out, so use negative margin.

Comment: Doh, I could have thought of that. :-) Thank you, I think I'm gonna use this.